# Push to an array if id value is not found

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've  a little array problem I'm going round and round in loops with.
I have a number of check boxes, each checkbox has a specific object.
On checking a checkbox I want to iterate over the array and if the id of the checkbox (object) does not match any other items in the array, push to the array.

I have the following, which pushes the checkbox object for every item that doesn't match it's id. So I end up with multiple objects of the same ID.

```
mapMarkers.map(marker => {
    if(markerID !== marker[0].id) {
        mapMarkers.push(markerObject)
    };
});
```

Any help to get my thinking on this straight would be appreciated.

For context here's the project its from. Lines 281
https://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/PQvMqR?editors=0011

Comment: Please post a [mcve] HERE

Comment: You are saying your `marker` is an array..... I am guessing it is not an array.

Comment: why map if the result is not taken? semicolon after block statement, really?

Comment: epascarello, marker is each item in the map.Markers array

Answer (score 0):

The `Array#filter` method would be more appropriate for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
const filteredMarkers = mapMarkers.filter(marker => markerID !== marker.id);
```

Then use `filteredMarkers` (`mapMarkers` isn't mutated, which is a better practice).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rem Lampa, It's certainly working better than It was but I only get the item with ID:0 plus the object pushed from the check box.